# Magento2: set credit card as default payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

How to set default payment method as authorize.net credit card for that I have tired to override

> Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\default.js

below is the code

```
define(['Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'], function(Component) {
    initObservable: function () {
        this._super();
        this.selectPaymentMethod();
    }
});
```

but got stuck how to override the particular method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me fine
**requirejs**

```
  var config = {
        config: {
            mixins: {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': {
                    'Vendor_CheckoutDefaultPayment/js/model/checkout-data-resolver-mixin': true
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

**checkout-data-resolver-mixin**

```
define([
        'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method'
    ], function (checkoutData, paymentService, selectPaymentMethodAction) {
        'use strict';    
    
        return function(checkoutDataResolver) {
            checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod= function () {
                var selectedPaymentMethod = checkoutData.getSelectedPaymentMethod(),
                    availablePaymentMethod = paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods();
                if(selectedPaymentMethod === null ){
                    availablePaymentMethod.some(function (payment) {
                        if(payment.method ==  'anet_creditcard'){
                            checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod('anet_creditcard');
                            var selectedPaymentMethodNew = checkoutData.getSelectedPaymentMethod();
                            if (payment.method == selectedPaymentMethodNew) { 
                                selectPaymentMethodAction(payment);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    availablePaymentMethod.some(function (payment) {
                        if (payment.method == selectedPaymentMethod) {
                            selectPaymentMethodAction(payment);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
    
            return checkoutDataResolver;
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod();
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                'payment',
                null,
                $t('Review & Payments'),
                this.isVisible,
                _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                this.sortOrder
            );

            return this;
        },
```

The above code is in `Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment.js`. It is loaded when you first visit the checkout page.

You can see that it called `checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod()`, which eventually set the payment method (get it from local storage).

You can set the data to local storage before it call the function `resolvePaymentMethod`, then when it invoke, it will get your pre-set data.

You can use mixin to overwrite this initialize method

```js
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data'
], function (checkoutData) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        initialize: function () {
            checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod('input-authorize.net-payment-code-here');
            this._super();
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept but using this code payment method stop loading

Comment: It depends on how you do it, I checked myself before posting this so I'm sure it works